# P(the parts will be joined in the original order), after each of $n$ sticks is broken into a long and short part - Feller problem 2.12

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

I would like someone to check my work on Problem 2.12 from Introduction to Probability Theory and its applications volume-I, William Feller. Do you think, the solution(approach) is correct?

[***Note***. *The question has been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883974/after-n-sticks-are-broken-into-two-parts-each-they-are-joined-again-randomly), but would like someone to proof-read my solution, as it looks different*.]

> Suppose that each of $n$ sticks is broken into one long and one short part. The $2n$ parts are arranged into $n$ pairs from which new sticks are formed. Find the probability (a) that the parts will be joined in the original order (b) that all long parts are paired with short parts.

**Solution**.
Let's use the artifice $(s_1,l_1),(s_2,l_2),\ldots,(s_n,l_n)$ to represent the $2n$ parts of $n$ sticks.

(a) There $(2n)!$ distinguishable arrangements of $2n$ parts. If we divide any sequence in pairs of two each, the order within each pair is unimportant. So, corresponding to each sequence, we overcounted by a factor of $2^n$. Moreover, the order amongst the pairs does not matter, and therefore, we overcounted by a factor of $n!$. Therefore, the number of distinct pairs that can be formed using $2n$ sticks are $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$.

There is only $1$ way to join the parts in the same order as the original one.

P(joining the parts in the original order) = $1 \div ((2n)!/2^n n!) = \frac{2^n n!}{(2n)!}$.

(b) Every long part must be paired with a short part. This could be done in :

1st pair : $2n \cdot n $ choices.

2nd pair : $(2n-2) \cdot (n-2)$ choices.

and so forth.

This results in $2^n (n!)^2$ arrangements. Adjusting for overcounting by a factor of $2^n n!$, this results in $n!$ pairs.

P(all long parts are paired with all short parts)=$n!\div((2n)!/(n! \cdot 2^n)) = \frac{(n!)^2 \cdot 2^n}{(2n)!}$.

Thanks so much!